# relaciones en laravel 3 tablas

Tags: laravel, controller, vistas

tengo 3 tablas:

Alumno(id)

Curso(id, nombre)

Matricula(id,id_alumno,id_curso)

Cuando hago login con un alumno en su cuenta recibo sus datos con:

```
$alumno = Alumno::find(auth('alumno')->user()->id);
```

he intentado llegar a la matricula con :

```
$matricula = Matricula::where('id_alumno',auth('alumno')->user()->id)->get();
```

En el modelo Matricula ya tengo la relacion para curso pero al hacer esto:

```
$matricula->curso;
```

Pero no me funciona la relacion, Como puedo obtener el nombre del curso de dicho alumno por medio de la matricula??

Modelo Matricula:

```
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curso::class,'id_curso','id');
}
public function alumno()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class,'id_alumno','id');
}
```

Modelo Curso:

```
public function matriculas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Matricula','id_curso');
}
```

Modelo Alumno

```
public function matriculas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Matricula','id_alumno');
}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de los 3 modelos, donde se definen las relaciones.

Comment: Agregado los modelos

Comment: lo que me fataba era el first()

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿sería una relación muchos a muchos entre alumnos y cursos? La respuesta aceptada es muy pobre si tenemos en cuenta las buenas prácticas y la potencia de Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo en tu caso realizaria algo similar a esto

```
$alumno = Auth::user()->id
```

Ya que tu tabla Alumno solo tiene un campo, con esto ya obtendrías el id requerido.

Ahora para matricula:

```
$matricula=Matricula::where('id_alumno','=',$alumno)->get()->first();
```

Esto no devuelve un objeto, por lo que no podrás aplicar $matricula->curso. El retorno de get() es un colección.

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias ahora me funciono